# Why the Web site project does not have release mode in config?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2008, build

I'm currently working in the **web site project**.I want to build project in **release** mode, that unfortunately saw visual studio does not have **release** mode for build and only have **debug** mode.

in **web application project** we see two option in build **debug** and **release**.

I want to know why web site project have debug mode in build.I was read about debug and release mode building that release mode have **optimize code** and have **less overhead**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set release meod  by right clicking solution > property> in dialog change it release mode or direclty from the rop of vidual studio set it for the release , see below image marked with red

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible for a WebSite and that it is only possible with Web Application.

Comment: @JordyvanEijk- it for entire solution not for the perticual project of solution

Comment: You can add an active solution configuration but how is it possible then to add the configuration and set it to release?

Comment: I think this is only possible to set the `<compilation targetFramework="4.0"/>` without the debug="true"

Comment: I do right-click in the solution and select property but I don't see  your mentioned config in dialog box.

Comment: I was mentioned in the top I'm using visual studio 2008 and no 2010

Answer (score 1):

In web site projects pages are compiled dynamically upon first request. It will compile without debugging symbols unless you specify otherwise in the config file.

You cant change it with configuration manager neither you see it in its options.

In your web config file find these options

```
<system.web>
 ...
<compilation debug="true">
...
</compilation>
</system.web>
```

Set true to false then it will publish in release mode. 
Hope it helps